# Waveform, polygonal?

Tags: 3d

I have no idea what they call this so I'm not having much success with searching. But lets start with an example at [this site](http://magicleap.com/#ourvision-home):

[image: waveform]

Any idea how to make the choppy sea like wave they're using? I had limited success in Maya but I could work on it more, however I was wondering if there was a quicker alternative? After effects maybe. I had a play with trapcode but didn't have the results I was after.

Maybe there isn't a quicker way to do it in which I'll use maya though ^^

Comment: I don't know what to call the style, but a search term that might help for After Effects features for things like this is `particle systems`. This tutorial might be relevant: http://www.videocopilot.net/tutorials/energy_wipe/ (taken from http://naldzgraphics.net/tutorials/50-most-amazing-adobe-after-effects-tutorials-you-need-to-learn/)

Comment: I was able to find some similar effects by searching for [wireframe waves](https://www.google.com/search?q=wireframe%20waves&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi). I also found a tutorial that might help: [Creating a Stormy Ocean in Maya](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/maya/stormyocean/). Perhaps you could use that as a guideline and export a wireframe render instead of the polished render

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest way to do this is to create a noise texture for a height/depth map and use it on a Terrain object or as a displacement map for a Plane/Polygon object.  Here is a sample map that I made:
[image: Depth Map]

At this point you can use the app of your choice, Bryce is free and makes terraines out of grayscale images.  For this example, and because this is a design question, I used **Photoshop CS 6 Extended** and the `Mesh from Depth Map > Plane` and create this object (after deleting Diffuse and keeping the auto-generated Opacity Map):
[image: Plane mesh from Depth Map with Diffuse removed]

I then edited the opacity map and create a black fill and then dark gray lines, to produce this effect:
[image: Opacity Map with black fill and dark gray stripes]

You can also turn off the Surface and enable Lines and Points in the 3D panel's Scene object to get this effect:
[image: Surface disabled with Lines and Points enabled]

This may be an effective way for you to create this effect, assuming you have Photoshop CS 6 Extended.  You may be able to do it with other version of Photoshop CS 3-5, but probably not as easily.  I hope this helps.  Cheers!

Comment: Brilliant. I had toyed with the idea of using a map in my head. I can use maya to create the displacement. I had gotten a great wave effect with a transform of a wave but couldnt render the transform itself or export it.

Comment: Also pleased it's about the photoshop part. Haven't really toyed with the new CS6 features.